How can I override specific styles in Jekyll Minimal Mistakes theme?
I am using the Minimal-Mistakes gem-installed theme and am using the neon skin with it. I really like what it offers out of the box but I do want to change the footer-background-color. What I have done so far in attempt to override the styles is the following:
Copy over _sass/minimal-mistakes for all the style imports that it provides. I just copied everything in here based on the instructions here.
Like I said, I didn't want to change much at first, I wanted to at least see if it was working. So I made a main.scss in my assets/css folder in root.
It looks like this:
/* assets/css/main.scss */
$footer-background-color: #ff0000;  // Set the footer background color here

@import "minimal-mistakes/skins/{{ site.minimal_mistakes_skin | default: 'default' }}"; // skin
@import "minimal-mistakes"; // main partials

Here I put the style I want to override before the import statements, like it says in the MM docs.
I also see this in my jekyll logs where it is hitting the main.scss file but is not doing anything:
    /home/malexander15/malexander15.github.io/assets/css/main.scss 4:9                                              root stylesheet
But I'm not entirely sure that means anything.
I didn't see anything else I was supposed to do after this in the docs. What exactly am I missing?
Also, this post is very very close to the same problem. The best answer on this post is very elaborate and verbose but I am confused by what they did for the actual solution and how to apply it in my situation.
I tried changing the background color of the footer for the minimal-mistakes theme, with the neon skin applied, from background-color: #18020a; to ff0000. Nothing appeared to change.

Does your assets/css/main.scss still include front matter? Preprocessing only happens if it does

It does not. I didn't think we needed that because when I copied it over from the source code, there were errors with that type of code in an SCSS file. I'll try putting it back with what was there.

Update: That worked! Thank you so much, this took way too much time out of my life. To anyone reading, if you don't think the dashes matter (front matter) when copying over the main.scss to your project, well it does... I wish I could upvote your comment @BenjaminW.

I added it as an answer.

If you look at the original main.scss, it starts with this front matter:
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
search: false
---

This could be phrased stronger: it must have front matter.
Even if you don't set anything in front matter, you still have to have it, or else Jekyll just copies the file as-is instead of processing it (to CSS, in this case).
This is mentioned in the Jekyll docs, under Assets:

Jekyll provides built-in support for Sass and can work with CoffeeScript via a Ruby gem. In order to use them, you must first create a file with the proper extension name (one of .sass, .scss, or .coffee) and start the file with two lines of triple dashes, like this:
---
---

// start content
.my-definition
  font-size: 1.2em



I at least made it the accepted answer. Whenever I gain 4 more reputation I will upvote it as well.
